# Piramide de numeros en python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

debo hacer una piramide que me algo asi
 n= 5

1

2 2

3 3 3

4 4 4 4

5 5 5 5 5

pero lo que intente hacer me da asi

numero n: 6

0 1 2 3 4 5 0
1 2 3 4 5 1
2 3 4 5 2
3 4 5 3
4 5 4
5 5
6

este es el codigo

```
numero=input("numero n: ")

numcol=0

while numcol<=numero:
   fila=numcol

    while (fila<numero):
       print fila,
       fila=fila+1

    print numcol,
    numcol=numcol+1
    print "\t"
```

ayuda XD

Comment: Hola! Podrías mostrar cómo quieres que te de la pirámide? Porque no le aplicaste el formato para que quede

Comment: Ahora si hehe perdon por eso XC

Answer (score 3):

Usando comprensión de listas puedes resolverlo de forma muy compacta:

```
lineas = 5
print("\n".join([str(l)*l for l in range(0,lineas+1)]))
```

- Nos apoyamos en el método `*` de las cadenas que replican la misma una `n` veces una determinada cadena
- Entonces con `[str(l)*l for l in range(0,lineas+1)]` generamos una lista para cada línea con el número y longitud deseada en cada caso
- Con `"\n".join()` juntamos cada línea en una única cadena con un salto de línea para cada elemento

Answer (score 0):

Bien, empecemos.

Lo que yo haría sería hacer una cadena con el número y un espacio, y luego imprimir la cadena

```
numero=int(input("numero n: "))

numcol=0

while numcol<numero:
    fila=numcol+1
    cont=0
    m=""
    while(cont<fila):
        m=m+str(numcol+1)+" " # si no necesitas el espacio, seria m=m+str(numcol+1)
        cont+=1
    print m
    numcol=numcol+1
```

Básicamente, fila guardaría el número que va en cada fila, por ejemplo, si es la fila 1, pues guarda el 1, y así. 
Con cont, lo que hago es repetir ese número la misma cantidad de veces que ese número dicte, si fila es igual a 1, pues, m será igual a "1", si fila es igual a 2, m será igual a "2 2" y luego, con el print m, voy mostrando las filas abajo de la otra quedando, si ingresas n=5 de esta forma:

```
1
2 2
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5
```

Véase que no puse, numcol menor o igual a número, sino que menor estricto, puesto que de ser igual, se repetiría n+1 veces y la última fila del ejemplo anterior sería `"6 6 6 6 6 6 "`

Saludos y espero te sirva!

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es usar [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

n = 5 #int(input("Introduzca numero: "))
renglones = [[i]*i for i in range(1, n+1)]
for renglon in renglones:
  print(reduce(lambda x, y: f"{x} {y}", renglon), sep='\n')
```

- Primero armamos los renglones por cada item, la variable renglones para `n=5` sería: `[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]`
- Para cada renglon usamos `reduce`, el primer argumento de `reduce` será una funcion (`lambda` en este caso) la cual será pasada por cada item de las sublistas.
- El argumento `sep` de la funcion `print` hace que tengamos el salto de linea correspondiente.

En una linea (pero perdiendo legibilidad):

```
[print(reduce(lambda x, y: f"{x} {y}", renglon), sep='\n') for renglon in [[i]*i for i in range(1, n+1)]][0]
```

Salida:

```
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

En Python, es muy sencillo repetir una cadena tantas veces como queramos. Tenemos que usar el operador * y especificar el número de veces que queremos repetir toda la cadena.

```py
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print(str(i)*i)
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).