# ¿Cómo creo una escalera de n escalones programáticamente?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Dado un número n se te pide dibujar una escalera de este tipo:
donde n es el numero de escaleras

```
|_
|.|_
|...|_
|.....|_
|.......|_
|.........|_
```

mi solucion se muestra asi

```
.|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
..|_|_|_|_|_|_
...|_|_|_|_|_
....|_|_|_|_
.....|_|_|_
......|_|_
```

si alguien me brinda su ayuda estaria muy agradecido

Comment: Hola, podrias compartir el codigo de tu solucion para poder ayudarte un poco mas

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Piramide de numeros en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/204960/piramide-de-numeros-en-python)

Answer (score 2):

En vez de darte una solución te explico cómo pensar para encontrar una, pues este sitio no es para resolver tareas académicas, sino para ayudar con dudas puntuales o errores en el código, pero no has puesto el tuyo.

A la hora de resolver un problema de este tipo lo primero es *buscar patrones repetitivos*, pues estos patrones se traducirán a bucles en el código.

Si examinas tu escalera:

```
|_
|.|_
|...|_
|.....|_
|.......|_
|.........|_
|...........|_
```

enseguida podrás ver un patrón repetitivo:

- Cada escalón es una línea en la salida
- Todas las líneas terminan con `|_`
- Todas las líneas salvo la primera comienzan por `|`
- Todas las líneas salvo la primera tienen una secuencia de `.` entre el `|` del inicio y el `|_` del final
- El número de `.` en cada línea depende de en qué escalón estemos.

Este último punto es importante pues tenemos que ser capaces de encontrar algún tipo de relación entre el número de escalón y el número de puntos. Si numeramos a los escalones desde arriba, siendo el escalón 0 el que solo tiene `|_` vemos que:

- El escalón 1 tiene 1 punto
- El escalón 2 tiene 3 puntos
- El escalón 3 tiene 5 puntos
- El escalón 4 tiene 7 puntos

Vemos por tanto que cada nuevo escalón tiene 2 puntos más que el anterior, por lo que el escalón número `n` tendrá `(n-1)*2` puntos más que el escalón 1, que tenía 1. Así que el número de puntos del escalón `n` debería ser `1 + (n-1)*2`.

Verifiquemos que se cumple:

- n=1 --> 1 + (1-1)*2 = 1 punto
- n=2 --> 1 + (2-1)*2 = 3 puntos
- n=3 --> 1 + (3-1)*2 = 5 puntos

parece que funciona.

Entonces ya tenemos el algoritmo general. Para pintar la escalera iremos iterando por el número de escalón (`n`), comenzando en 0. Para cada valor de `n`  debemos pintar el escalón `n`-ésimo, el cual se pinta así: si `n>=1`, pintamos el `|` inicial, y después pintamos `1+(n-1)*2` puntos. Finalmente pintamos el `|_` que va al final de todos los escalones.

El pseudocódigo sería por tanto:

```
para cada n entre 0 y el número de escalones a pintar:
  si n >= 1:
     pintar "|"
     calcular número de puntos como 1+(n-1)*2
     pintar ese número de puntos (puede requerir otro bucle)
  pintar "|_"
  avanzar línea
```

Ya sólo te queda convertir ese pseudocódigo en Python. Si al hacerlo encuentras problemas, no dudes en abrir una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

¿Algo así?

```
def escalones(escalones):
    print('|_')
    for i in range(0, escalones):
        print('|' + '.'*(1+i*2) + '|_')
```

corre:

```
escalones(6)

|_
|.|_
|...|_
|.....|_
|.......|_
|.........|_
|...........|_
```