# Triángulo de números palíndromos en python 3

Tags: python-3.x

espero que tengan un buen día. Tengo el siguiente problema y es que hice un ejemplo en python 2, creyendo que funcionaría en python 3... Vaya idea, acá dejo el código de python 2

```
def Piramide(lineas):
    
    fila = 0;
    for i in range(1,lineas+1):
            fila +=2;
            for j in range(lineas-i):
              print " ",
            for k in range(i,fila):
              print k%10,
            for l in range(fila-2,i-1,-1):
              print l%10,
            

            print 
       
    return 
  
Piramide(10)
```

Lo que necesito que haga es básicamente esto
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321

En forma de pirámide, y no sé como hacerlo, ¿Me podrían ayudar? O si me pueden decir alguna forma más fácil de hacerlo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: y si no funciona en Python3, ¿no te parece que conviene que especifiques en qupe lugar falla y cuál es el error? Por ejemplo, si no te funciona `print " "`, ¿probaste buscar el porqué y si no cambió eso?... Cualquier pregunta que hagas, conviene que seas lo más específico posible, así vas a tener más chances de que te respondan

Comment: Este es el primer resultado que sale en Google al buscar "*diferencias entre Python 2 y 3*" https://www.programaenpython.com/miscelanea/diferencias-entre-python-2-y-3/... fijate cuál es la primer diferencia que aparece!!!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Piramide de numeros en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/204960/piramide-de-numeros-en-python)

Answer (score 0):

Como en todas las versiones, suele haber cambios entre una versión y otra de todos los lenguajes, mucho más si es un cambio completo de versión y se pasa de la 2 a la 3.

Este caso es muy sencillo de solucionar, tan solo tienes que adaptar todas las funciones `print` a `print()` que es la manera correcta en Python 3. Tu programa quedaría así:

```
def Piramide(lineas):
    
    fila = 0;
    for i in range(1,lineas+1):
            fila +=2;
            for j in range(lineas-i):
              print(" "),
            for k in range(i,fila):
              print(k%10),
            for l in range(fila-2,i-1,-1):
              print(l%10),
            

            print() 
       
    return 
  
Piramide(10)
```